# facebook and twitter in .net

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, twitter

can any one give the demo
 how to implement facebook like box( single sign - on) and  twitter's tweets for a web application using .net(c#)

Comment: what do you mean with the facebook like box? do you want to couple your application with facebook ?

Comment: yes i want in my application to show a facebook likebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this [article](http://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/DevelopingFacebookApplicationsInCWithASPNET.aspx) about how to implement facebook login in a .net web application. If you want to display tweets on your page, you basically just add some javascript to your page. See the [twitter API wiki](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/) for more info.

Comment: sorry I need to use codeplex for this can anyone show it is to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Facebook like box to your page is really easy, you can check out the [Facebook Developers Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box), there's even a 'Get Code' button to get the necessary code.

All you need to do is add a script reference and a `<fb:like>` tag, all the options are in the above link.